# Possible? How to setup VNC in a Google Managed VM Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, vnc, managed-vm, google-managed-vm

I'm using Java but this isn't necessarily a Java question.  Google's "java-compat" image is Debian (3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3~bpo70+1 (2016-01-19)).

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/java-compat
RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get qqy install curl xvfb x11vnc
RUN mkdir -p ~/.vnc
RUN x11vnc -storepasswd xxxxxxxx ~/.vnc/passwd 
EXPOSE 5900

ADD . /app
```

And in the Admin Console I created a firewall rule to open up 5900.  And lastly I am calling the vnc server itself in the "_ah/start" startup hook with this command:

```
x11vnc -forever -usepw -create
```

All seems to be setup correctly but I'm unable to connect with TightVNC.  I use the public (ephemeral) IP address for the instance I find in the Admin Console followed by ::5900 (TightVNC requires two colons for some reason).  I'm getting a message that the server refused the connection.  And indeed when I try to telnet to port 5900 it's blocked.

Next I SSH into the *container* machine and when I test the port on the container with wget xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5900 I get a connection.  So it seems to me the container is not accepting connections on port 5900.  Am I getting this right?  Is it possible to open up ports and route my VNC client into the docker container?  Any help appreciated.

**Why I can't use Compute Engine.**  Just to preempt some comments about using google's Compute Engine environment instead of Managed VMs.  I make heavy use of the Datastore and Task Queues in my code.  I don't think those can run (or run natively/efficiently) on Compute Engine.  But I may pose that as a separate question.

**Update:** Per Paul in the comments... having learned some of the docker terminology: Can I publish a port on the container in Google's environment?

Comment: I believe expose only exposes the port to other docker instances. Try publishing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker

Comment: Great reference Paul.  I think that's my problem--I don't have control over the "docker run" parameters to put that "-p" flag in.  That command is executed by the Google environment (hence the "managed" in managed vm).

Comment: fyi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602132/how-do-i-access-my-appengine-datastore-entities-from-my-compute-engine-vm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity - why are you trying to VNC into your instances? If it's just for management purposes, you can SSH into Managed VM instances.

[image: Use SSH instead of VNC if you can]

That having been said - you can use the network/forwarded_ports config to route traffic from the VM to the application container:

```
network:
  forwarded_ports:
  - 5900
  instance_tag: vnc
```

Put that in your app.yaml, and re-deploy your app.  You'll also need to open the port in your firewall (if you intend on accessing this from the public internet):

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-vnc \
  --allow tcp:5900 \
  --target-tags vnc \
  --description "Allow vnc traffic on port 5900"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Those settings on app.yaml were the deep magic that I needed!  Thank you Justin.  I wonder what other undocumented secrets are lurking in app.yaml....

Comment: Ha, glad it was helpful.  FWIW, we do have this covered here:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

Comment: Also - I have to know - why are you using VNC here?

Comment: Top secret.  But it involves world domination.  And the evils of GUI app automation in a headless environment.  As for the app.yaml documentation... I've made a "note to self" that if I *really* want to search the docs I'll have to go through each language... those details on the Node.js side are nowhere to be found in Python or Java configs.

Comment: Sorry about that - looks like google search hasn't caught up with google cloud yet :P  It's the same doc in each language:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml